# Page control with image array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipagecontrol

I am trying to make a page control associated with an image array. I had it setup correctly just changing the background color and load in the initial image, but when I scroll nothing further is shown. Here is my code:

```
var images: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "slide1.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "loginButton.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "slide1.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "slide1.png")!
]

func setPageViewinScroll() {

    for index in 0..<4 {

        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size
        self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
        self.imageView.image = images[index]
        let subview = UIView(frame: frame)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(subview)
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 4, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)

    pageControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector("changePage:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)



}

func changePage(sender: AnyObject) -> () {
        let x = CGFloat(pageControl.currentPage) * scrollView.frame.size.width
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(x, 0), animated: true)
    }
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding your UIImageview to UIScrollview instead of UIView like this code?

```
var imageOne:UIImageView!
var imageTwo:UIImageView!
var imageThree:UIImageView!
var imageFour:UIImageView!

func functionCalledFromViewDidLoad() {

    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width,self.view.frame.height)

    let scrollViewWidth = scrollView.frame.width
    let scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.height

    imageOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0,scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))
    imageTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollViewWidth*1, 0,scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))
    imageThree = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollViewWidth*2, 0,scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))
    imageFour = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollViewWidth*3, 0,scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))

    scrollView.addSubview(imageOne)
    scrollView.addSubview(imageTwo)
    scrollView.addSubview(imageThree)
    scrollView.addSubview(imageFour)

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {


    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.width * 4, scrollView.frame.height)
    imageOne.frame.size.height = scrollView.frame.height
    imageTwo.frame.size.height = scrollView.frame.height
    imageThree.frame.size.height = scrollView.frame.height
    imageFour.frame.size.height = scrollView.frame.height
}
```

You also seem to need to add this code.

```
 func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    // Test the offset and calculate the current page after scrolling ends
    let pageWidth:CGFloat = CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.frame)

    let currentPage = Int(floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x-pageWidth/2)/pageWidth)+1)

     // Change the page indicator
     self.pageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
 }
```

There is a very good tutorial related to this topic, [here](http://sweettutos.com/2015/04/13/how-to-make-a-horizontal-paging-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-storyboards-swift/)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the image on the imageView and not on the subView.  I.o.w.  You are adding the subview to each page, but not setting the image on it.

**Change the subview code to the following**

```
let subview = UIImageView(frame: frame)
subview.image = images[index]
self.scrollView.addSubview(subview)
```